# What is the difference between NameNode and NameSpace

Tags: hadoop, namespaces, namenode

As a beginner to Hadoop, I am confused between NameNode and Namespace. From my understanding both of them have the same functionality, which they both contains metadata.

Is there any difference between them?

Comment: This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23924959/2302572) might help

Comment: @ShriroopJoshi, thanks! will check on it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NameNode is a Machine which will contain (Store) the namespace.

The NameNode’s primary responsibility is storing the HDFS namespace. Namespace is a hierarchy of files and directories. This means things like the directory tree, file permissions, and the mapping of files to block IDs.

In Hadoop 2.x took this a step further with the introduction of Federation, although its main purpose was to solve scaling issues in the namenode